# Can I apply different styles to columns in column-count?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout, column-count

Is there any way to add different styles for columns made with `column-count`? I have a `div` which is divided into multiple columns using `column-count`. At a time only two columns are visible on page. I need to add `margin-left` to the first column and `margin-right` for the second column and so on.

What I need is the same spacing on both (outer and inner) sides of the pages just like book.

```css
.main {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 438px;
  column-gap: 160px;
  columns: 2 auto;
  column-fill: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  Wikidata is a free, collaborative, multilingual, secondary database, collecting structured data to provide support for Wikipedia, Wikimedia Commons, the other wikis of the Wikimedia movement, and to anyone in the world. What does this mean? Let's look
  at the opening statement in more detail: Contents 1 What does this mean? 2 How does Wikidata work? 2.1 The Wikidata repository 2.2 Working with Wikidata 3 Where to get started 4 How can I contribute? 5 There is more to come Free. The data in Wikidata
  is published under the Creative Commons Public Domain Dedication 1.0, allowing the reuse of the data in many different scenarios. You can copy, modify, distribute and perform the data, even for commercial purposes, without asking for permission. Collaborative.
  Data is entered and maintained by Wikidata editors, who decide on the rules of content creation and management. Automated bots also enter data into Wikidata. Multilingual. Editing, consuming, browsing, and reusing the data is fully multilingual. Data
  entered in any language is immediately available in all other languages. Editing in any language is possible and encouraged. A secondary database. Wikidata records not just statements, but also their sources, and connections to other databases. This
  reflects the diversity of knowledge available and supports the notion of verifiability. Collecting structured data. Imposing a high degree of structured organization allows for easy reuse of data by Wikimedia projects and third parties, and enables
  computers to process and “understand” it. Support for Wikimedia wikis. Wikidata assists Wikipedia with more easily maintainable information boxes and links to other languages, thus reducing editing workload while improving quality. Updates in one language
  are made available to all other languages. Anyone in the world. Anyone can use Wikidata for any number of different ways by using its application programming interface. How does Wikidata work? This diagram of a Wikidata item shows you the most important
  terms in Wikidata. Wikidata is a central storage repository that can be accessed by others, such as the wikis maintained by the Wikimedia Foundation. Content loaded dynamically from Wikidata does not need to be maintained in each individual wiki project.
  For example, statistics, dates, locations and other common data can be centralized in Wikidata. The Wikidata repository Items and their data are interconnected. The Wikidata repository consists mainly of items, each one having a label, a description
  and any number of aliases. Items are uniquely identified by a Q followed by a number, such as Douglas Adams (Q42). Statements describe detailed characteristics of an Item and consist of a property and a value. Properties in Wikidata have a P followed
  by a number, such as with educated at (P69). For a person, you can add a property to specifying where they were educated, by specifying a value for a school. For buildings, you can assign geographic coordinates properties by specifying longitude and
  latitude values. Properties can also link to external databases. A property that links an item to an external database, such as an authority control database used by libraries and archives, is called an identifier. Special Sitelinks connect an item
  to corresponding content on client wikis, such as Wikipedia, Wikibooks or Wikiquote. All this information can be displayed in any language, even if the data originated in a different language. When accessing these values, client wikis will show the
  most up-to-date data. Item Property Value Q42 P69 Q691283 Douglas Adams educated at St John's College Working with Wikidata There are a number of ways to access Wikidata using built-in tools, external tools, or programming interfaces. Wikidata Query
  and Reasonator are some of the popular tools to search for and examine Wikidata items. The tools page has an extensive list of interesting projects to explore. Client wikis can access data for their pages using a Lua Scribunto interface. You can retrieve
  all data independently using the Wikidata API. Where to get started The Wikidata tours designed for new users are the best place to learn more about Wikidata. Some links to get started: Set your user options, especially the 'Babel' extension, to choose
  your language preferences Help with missing labels and descriptions Help with interwiki conflicts and constraint violations Improve a random item Help translating How can I contribute? Go ahead and start editing. Editing is the best way to learn about
  the structure and concepts of Wikidata. If you would like to gain understanding of Wikidata's concepts upfront, you may want to have a look at the help pages. If you have questions, please feel free to drop them in the project chat or contact the development
  team. There is more to come Wikidata is an ongoing project that is under active development. More data types as well as extensions will be available in the future. You can find more information about Wikidata and its ongoing development on the Wikidata
  page on Meta. Subscribe to the the Wikidata mailing list to receive up-to-date information about the development and to participate in discussions about the future of the project. North Korea conducted its sixth nuclear test on 3 September 2017, according
  to Japanese and South Korean officials. The Japanese Ministry of Foreign Affairs also concluded that North Korea conducted a nuclear test.[6] The United States Geological Survey reported an earthquake of 6.3-magnitude not far from North Korea's Punggye-ri
  nuclear test site.[7] South Korean authorities said the earthquake seemed to be artificial, consistent with a nuclear test.[6] The USGS, as well as China's earthquake administration, reported that the initial event was followed by a second, smaller,
  earthquake at the site, several minutes later, which was characterized as a collapse of the cavity.[8][9] North Korea claimed that it detonated a hydrogen bomb that can be loaded on to an intercontinental ballistic missile (ICBM) with great destructive
  power.[10] Photos of North Korean leader Kim Jong-un inspecting a device resembling a thermonuclear weapon warhead were released a few hours before the test.[11] Contents 1 Yield estimates 2 Reactions 3 See also 4 References Yield estimates According
  to estimates of Kim Young-Woo, the chief of the South Korean parliament's defense committee, the nuclear yield was equivalent to about 100 kilotons of TNT (100 kt). "The North's latest test is estimated to have a yield of up to 100 kilotons, though
  it is a provisional report," Kim Young-Woo told Yonhap News Agency.[2] On 3 September, South Korea’s weather agency, the Korea Meteorological Administration, estimated that the nuclear blast yield of the presumed test was between 50 to 60 kilotons.[3]
  On 4 September, the academics from University of Science and Technology of China[12] have released their findings based on seismic results and concluded that the Nuclear Test Location is at 41°17′53.52″N 129°4′27.12″E on 03:30 UTC which is only a few
  hundred meters apart from the previous 4 tests (2009, 2013, January 2016 and September 2016) with the estimated yield at 108.1 ± 48.1 kt. In contrast, the independent seismic monitoring agency NORSAR estimated that the blast had a yield of about 120
  kilotons, based on a seismic magnitude of 5.8.[4] The Federal Institute for Geosciences and Natural Resources in Germany estimates a higher yield at "a few hundred kilotons" based on a detected tremor of 6.1 magnitude.[5] Reactions South Korea, China,
  Japan, Russia and members of the ASEAN[13] voiced strong criticism of the nuclear test.[14] US President Donald Trump tweeted "North Korea has conducted a major Nuclear Test. Their words and actions continue to be very hostile and dangerous to the United
  States".[15][16] Trump was asked whether the US would attack North Korea and replied, "We'll see".[17] On September 3, U.S. Defense Secretary James Mattis warned North Korea, saying that the country would be met with a "massive military response" if
  it threatened the United States or its allies.[18] The United Nations Security Council will meet in an open emergency meeting on September 4, 2017 at the request of the US, South Korea, Japan, France and the UK.[19] Federal Institute for Geosciences
  and Natural Resources From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia (Redirected from Bundesanstalt für Geowissenschaften und Rohstoffe) Federal Institute for Geosciences and Natural Resources Bundesanstalt für Geowissenschaften und Rohstoffe (BGR) Agency overview
  Headquarters Hanover, Germany Employees 795 in 2013 Website www.bgr.bund.de The Federal Institute for Geosciences and Natural Resources (Bundesanstalt für Geowissenschaften und Rohstoffe or BGR) is a German agency within the Federal Ministry of Economics
  and Technology. It acts as a central geoscience consulting institution for the German federal government.[1] The headquarters of the agency is located in Hanover and there is a branch in Berlin. Early 2013, the BGR employed a total of 795 employees.
  The BGR, the State Authority for Mining, Energy and Geology and the Leibniz Institute for Applied Geophysics form the Geozentrum Hanover. All three institutions have a common management and infrastructure, and complement each other through their interdisciplinary
  expertise.
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle for testing [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r38jado4/)

Comment: Add the code you are working on, and link up the inspirational image you want to achieve.

Comment: I'd say just put this this inside another div and give that one a padding.